# How to add public key identity from String?

Tags: ssh-keys, apache-sshd

I have a Spring Boot application with [Apache SSHD](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/). The application should use [SSH Public Key Authentication](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/public-key-authentication). Therefore, the application needs a private key. How to provide this private key?

For security reasons, the private key should not be saved in the

- source code (in Git)
- classpath (in JAR)
- image (in Docker Registry)
- host/volume (with Docker Mount)

Instead the private key should be provided as an environment variable (with GitLab).

**Documentation**

In the documentation is only an example for private keys saved in the filesystem, see [Loading key files](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/master/docs/client-setup.md#loading-key-files):

> **Loading key files**
>
> In order to use password-less authentication the user needs to provide one or more `KeyPair`-s that are used to "prove" the client's identity for the server. The code supports most if not all of the currently used key file formats. See `SshKeyDumpMain` class for example of how to load files - basically:
>
> ```
> KeyPairResourceLoader loader = SecurityUtils.getKeyPairResourceParser();
> Collection<KeyPair> keys = loader.loadKeyPairs(null, filePath, passwordProvider);
> ```

**Research**

I could create the the `KeyPair` as described in [create java PrivateKey and PublicKey from a String of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056036/create-java-privatekey-and-publickey-from-a-string-of-file), but then I would reimplement an existing part of Apache SSHD. I have to support all of the currently used key file formats.

**Question**

How to load private key from `String` instead of filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to use a `String` instead of a file, see [`KeyPairResourceLoader#loadKeyPairs`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.sshd/sshd-common/2.9.0/org/apache/sshd/common/config/keys/loader/KeyPairResourceLoader.html#loadKeyPairs-org.apache.sshd.common.session.SessionContext-org.apache.sshd.common.NamedResource-org.apache.sshd.common.config.keys.FilePasswordProvider-java.lang.String-):

> ```
> default Collection<KeyPair> loadKeyPairs(SessionContext session,
>                                     NamedResource resourceKey,
>                                     FilePasswordProvider passwordProvider,
>                                     String data)
>                              throws IOException,
>                                     GeneralSecurityException
> ```
>
> **Throws:**
> `IOException`
> `GeneralSecurityException`

My changed code:

```java
KeyPairResourceLoader loader = SecurityUtils.getKeyPairResourceParser();
Collection<KeyPair> keyPairCollection = loader.loadKeyPairs(null, null, null, pem);
```